# Variable doesn't accumulate over time?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Okay well I'm new to python, and I'm taking a class in school for this, and I'm a bit confused this. We are writing a program/script to calculate transactions from buying and selling shares and for some reason I cant get the "balance" variable to accumulate over time and be subtracted from and added to from buying and selling the shares. Here's the code. Any input would be amazing ^.^

```
def main():

    #Below is the variables used in the context

    balance = float(input("Starting cash amount? "))
    numtrades = int(input("Number of trades for today?"))
    print('You do not own any shares, but have', balance, 'in cash')
    buy = 0
    sell = 0
    price_per_share = 0
    transaction_amount = 0
    transaction_amount_buy = 0
    transaction_amount_sell = 0


    #Below is the prompt for the first transaction, which requires a buy

    num_shares = int(input('Number of shares to buy?'))
    price_per_share = float(input('Price per share?'))
    print(num_shares, "shares for $",price_per_share, "per share cost $",price_per_share * num_shares)
    buy = buy + num_shares
    transaction_amount_buy = transaction_amount_buy + (num_shares * price_per_share)
    print("Currently holding", buy, "and have $", balance - transaction_amount_buy , "in cash")


    if balance < transaction_amount :

            print('You do not have sufficient funds to purchase', num_shares, 'for $', price_per_share, 'per share.')
            print('Your current balance is', balance, ', but', num_shares,' x ', price_per_share,' = ', num_shares * price_per_share)
            print("Currently holding", buy, "and have $", balance - transaction_amount , "in cash")




    #Below is the loop counter for each trade, along with if statements for buy/sell


    for i in range(numtrades):
        print('Trade number', (i + 2), end = "")
        action = input(' (buy/sell)?')
        if action == 'buy':
            num_shares = int(input('Number of shares to buy?'))
        if action == 'sell':
            num_shares = int(input('Number of shares to sell?'))
        price_per_share = float(input('Price per share?'))
        print('Transaction', (i+2))
        print('Transaction type is', action)


        if action == 'buy':
            print(num_shares, "shares for $",price_per_share, "per share cost $",price_per_share * num_shares)
            buy = buy + num_shares
            transaction_amount_buy = transaction_amount_buy + (num_shares * price_per_share)

        if action == 'sell':
            print(num_shares, 'shares for $',price_per_share, 'per share worth $',price_per_share * num_shares)
            sell = sell + num_shares
            transaction_amount_sell = transaction_amount_sell + (num_shares * price_per_share)

        transaction_amount = transaction_amount_buy - transaction_amount_sell

        if balance < transaction_amount :

            print('You do not have sufficient funds to purchase', num_shares, 'for $', price_per_share, 'per share.')
            print('Your current balance is', balance - transaction_amount, ', but', num_shares,' x ', price_per_share,' = ', num_shares * price_per_share)
            print("Currently holding", buy, "and have $", balance - transaction_amount , "in cash")


        if balance > transaction_amount :
            print("Currently holding", buy, "and have $", balance - transaction_amount , "in cash")

 main()
```

Comment: Where in your code are you modifying the `balance` variable after the initial user input?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You print the difference, `balance - transaction_amount`, but you never set this value to the `balance` variable. Pretty much, you're doing something identical to:

```
>>> cupcakes = 5
>>> print("I ate one cupcake, now I have", cupcakes - 1, "cupcakes")
I ate one cupcake, now I have 4 cupcakes
>>> print(cupcakes)
5 # We never modified the variable cupcakes
```

Before your print statements, do `balance = balance - transaction_amount` (or `balance -= transaction_amount`), then in the print function just put `balance`.

Comment: @Hairo, I really appreciate your answer, would you mind elaborating using the code given? I've added,  `balance = balance - transaction_amount`  but the balance just turns back the defualt. :/

Comment: @Christian Make sure you're putting it everywhere before the print statements.

Comment: @Haidro, If I put it after the last 2 print statements it calculates it correctly until it hits the IF statement about how if the total price is > the balance to say i have insufficient funds and resort back to the previous amount of shares bought and balance....oh man, sorry for asking so many questions.

Comment: @YourFriend Wherever you have a print function which has `balance - transaction_armount`, put `balance = balance - transaction_amount` before it. Then, replace the balance - transaction_armount` in the print function with just `balance`

Comment: @Haidro, It still seems to go into a negative balance once it gets past the current balances value. so if you have 5,000$ and the cost is 7,500$ it freaks out. Nonethless I marked your answer as the correct one, since you helped me understand a bit more. Here's a paste bin to what i ended up with http://pastebin.com/uWZrDv9S , if you have any futher comments you might want to mention. I'd really appreciate it, nonetheless, i hope your day is filled with plenty of positive vibes.

Comment: @YourFriend Ah. For when `balance < transaction`, you **don't** want to lower your balance, because we never buy any shares (as we don't have the money, right?). ANyways, thanks for the accept :).

Comment: @Haidro, ah okay, so it'd just leave `balance < transaction` as `if balance < transaction_amount :

            print('You do not have sufficient funds to purchase', num_shares, 'for $', price_per_share, 'per share.')
            print('Your current balance is', balance, ', but', num_shares,' x ', price_per_share,' = ', num_shares * price_per_share)
            print("Currently holding", buy, "and have $", balance, "in cash") ` ?

Comment: @YourFriend Yep! And sorry, I did mean `balance < transaction_amount` above :p

Answer (score 1):

```
transaction_amount_buy = transaction_amount_buy + (num_shares * price_per_share)
balance = balance - transaction_amount_buy
print("Currently holding", buy, "and have $", balance , "in cash")
```

That should get the first section working, now the rest should follow...

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you break this problem down to a series of smaller problems. Do that by creating functions that deal solely with the smaller problem. Get each function working, before trying to hook them all together in main.

Example: You have a balance, whether you have purchased something or not.
You elect to purchase or sell. What are you buying or selling? Do you own it if you are selling? If not, is that ok? Is it different selling (shorting) something that you do not own.

So keep it simple, to start. Assume that you are only buying or selling bananas. Is buying 100 bananas different from selling 100 bananas? Not really if you deal with buying being a number greater than 0 and selling being a number less than zero.

So you have a (cash) balance. When you "buy", you return the cost. The balance should be decremented by the cost. If you, sell, the balance should be incremented by the cost.

Hmm.. Can you sell something that you don't own? It seems like you need to track not only your balance, but also your "position", holdings in the commodity being bought or sold.

If you can't sell more than you own, or buy bananas that cost more than your balance, you need to have a way to handle those issues.